# Preserving variable names in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

in Mathematica, i am trying to manipulate a list such that i can start with something like:

```
myList = List[{a,b,c,d}];

a=12;

b=15;

c=7;

d=9;
```

I would then like to be able to reorder the list with the output being the variable names instead of numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't you use an [association](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)?

Comment: You can also likely work with rules `{a->12,b->15}` . (association is new in version 10 by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @george in comment, one of the simplest way to do what you want 
is to use transformation rules. They allow to substitute a value for 
a symbol, without assigning a value to that symbol. For instance in your case
(I have mangled the order because it is not relevant here):

```
myValues = {d->9, a->12, b->15, c->7}
```

Transformation rules have two arguments and you can extract them. So here is a way to get the list of symbols from a list of transformation rules. The `Sort` is here to have the symbols in the alphabetical order.

```
myList = Sort[Map[First, myValues]]

{a, b, c, d}
```

To get a list of values, just apply the transformation rules to a list of symbol
with the `/.` operator

```
myList /. myValues 

{12, 15, 7, 9}
```

Now we know how to do that, we can sort the symbol according to their numerical value

```
mySortedList = myList[[Ordering[ myList /. myValues]]]

{c, d, a, b}
```

Ordering gives the position of elements in a list if they were sorted.
Here we use the list of numerical values and apply its order to the list of symbols.

As there is no `OrderingBy` command in Mathematica as far as I know, you can
also order the symbols by a given function by applying it inside Ordering this way :

```
myList[[Ordering[Map[EulerPhi, myList /. myValues]]]]

{a, c, d, b}
```

I hope it fits your application.

One thing one does very often in Mathematica is to keep the association between symbols and values in form of transformation rules and manipulate it.

In your case, it could take this form :

```
SortBy[ myValues, Last]

{c -> 7, d -> 9, a -> 12, b -> 15}
```

or

```
SortBy[myValues, EulerPhi[Last[#]] &]

{a -> 12, c -> 7, d -> 9, b -> 15}
```

Then you can choose to extract what you want.  That's how graph information is manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

```
myList = HoldForm[{a, b, c, d}];

a = 12;
b = 15;
c = 7;
d = 9;

Last /@ Sort[{ReleaseHold[#], #} & /@ Thread[myList]]
```

> {c, d, a, b}